# How to use value on address acquired from mmap?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm, mmap

having this nasm:

```
%define O_RDONLY 0
%define PROT_READ 0x1
%define MAP_PRIVATE 0x2

section .data
fname: db 'test.txt', 0

section .text
global _start
print:
 ; ---- THIS PART ADDED
    mov r15, [rdi]
    add r15, 1 ; have tried `inc byte[rdi]` - did not work either
    mov [rdi], r15
 ; ---- END OF ADDED PART
 ; else is according to book (so correct)
    push rdi


    call str_len
    pop rsi
    mov rdx, rax
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
    ret
str_len:
    xor rax, rax
.loop:
    cmp byte [rdi+rax], 0
    je .end
    inc rax
    jmp .loop
.end:
    ret

_start:
    ;call open
    mov rax, 2
    mov rdi, fname
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY 
    mov rdx, 0 
    syscall

    ;mmap
    mov r8, rax 
    mov rax, 9 
    mov rdi, 0 
    mov rsi, 4094 
    mov rdx, PROT_READ 
    mov r10, MAP_PRIVATE  
    mov r9, 0 
    syscall

    mov rdi, rax ;returned address 
    call print
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

The file `test.txt` contains only one char at the beginning - `5`.

I got address from region asked by `mmap` in `rax`, which I then `mov`e to `rdi`.
And I simply want to increment the value (at that address - now being in `rdi`):

```
    mov r15, [rdi]
    add r15, 1 ; have tried `inc byte[rdi]` - did not work either
    mov [rdi], r15
    push rdi
```

So i temporary `mov`e the value on `r15`, the increment it (`add` it 1), and try to `mov`e it back to address of that region (address still in `rdi`). But then `segfault`.

Why is that? Why cannot I use the value on the address (to the acquired region from mmap), which contain `5` - one byte (on which the `rdi` points), and use it in arithmetic?

If that would be address declared in `data segment`, then there would be no problem (I have tried). But the address is from `mmap`, So how does it differ, and how to fix that?

Comment: did you use `strace` to check that mmap is even returning a pointer, not an error code?  A `mov [rdi], r15` store into PROT_READ (without PROT_WRITE) memory looks like an obvious reason for it to segfault anyway, though.  Use a debugger so see which instruction it faults on.

Comment: @Peter, yes it does. The code is correct (as again -from book), I just added the part when trying to use the the value (on the address returned) by indirect addressing.

Comment: As I said. It works from address being initialized in data segment, but cannot use address from mmap on runtime

Comment: @PeterCordes, is not the problem that I am asking memory of size one page (4096), but want the value of the address at the beginning (which mmap return in rax), but accessing only one byte? (the first one). Is not that the cause of the issue?

Comment: @PeterCordes otherwise how can I store a value at the address the mmap return? I am trying to do so by indirect addressing, but as the problem - getting sigseg instead.

Comment: You’re opening the file read-only and calling map with PROT_READ (not PROT_WRITE), and then you get an error when you try to write to it, exactly as expected.

Comment: @prl https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225161/is-overbuffered-done-on-10th-byte-past-alocated-space

Comment: @Herdsman, I don’t see the relevance of that link to this question or to my comment. There’s no mmap there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Writing to read-only memory segfaults** (`mov [rdi], r15` qword store, or `inc byte [rdi]` byte RMW).

You need `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE` if you want to be able to write as well as read.

(Note that writing to a MAP_PRIVATE mapping triggers a copy-on-write, leaving you with a private page that's no longer backed by the file, just like if you'd done a `read` into a MAP_ANONYMOUS page.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the `copy-on-write` mechanism, or how it works? What do you mean by `leaving you with a private page that's no longer backed by the file`, why does writing to a private page change it to anonymous page? I though every page are backed either by file or a object (they correspond to). I know only stack to be anonymous (but code segment should be always backed with a exe file, or not?). Can you add a little to your answer?

Comment: @Herdsman: google on those phrases, especially "copy on write", e.g. [What is copy-on-write?](//stackoverflow.com/q/628938).  MAP_PRIVATE means writes to those pages aren't reflected in the file contents, thus the page effectively becomes anonymous and could only be paged out to swap space, not any file.  e.g. [Mmap() an entire large file](//stackoverflow.com/q/7222164)  If you have a different question about how mmap works, ask it; this question isn't the place for a guide to what mmap does, or about MAP_ANONYMOUS for allocating new anonymous pages other than stack and BSS.